# How to make the BuddyBar fix and scroll with the page

Tags: buddypress, admin-bar

I've been trying to find a way to force the BuddyBar to scroll with the page instead of float at the top of the browser window when scrolling down the page.

I been searching the net for this but can't seem to find anything on it anywhere. Has anyone tried this yet?

This is on a multisite install.

Comment: I'm actually going to advise against this. In the next version of WordPress, we've added a feature where clicking on an empty portion of the toolbar will automatically take you back to the top of the page.  If the toolbar moves when you scroll the page, you won't be able to use this navigational feature ...

Answer (score 1):

I believe that's `#wp-admin-bar`. At least it is on Wordpress 3.3.1 and BP 1.5.4

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the css `position:fixed` to `position:absolute` for `#wpadminbar`:

```
#wpadminbar {
    position: absolute;
}
```

You can put the following in your `function.php`

```
//hook the header output to make the BuddyBar fix and scroll with the page
add_action('wp_head', 'azizur_buddybar_scrolled');

function azizur_buddybar_scrolled() {
    echo '<style type="text/css">#wpadminbar {position: absolute;}</style>';
}
```